# use java regex,how can i get group value with "( )" string?

Tags: java, regex

I have strings:

```
 @Table(name = "T_MEM_MEMBER_ADDRESS1")
 @Table(  name = "T_MEM_MEMBER_ADDRESS2")
 @Table (   name = "T_MEM_MEMBER_ADDRESS3" )
```

I want to write a regex, which can get the name value,such as :

```
 T_MEM_MEMBER_ADDRESS1
 T_MEM_MEMBER_ADDRESS2
 T_MEM_MEMBER_ADDRESS3
```

I write

```
String regexPattern="...";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

boolean matches = matcher.matches();
if (matches){
   log.debug(matcher.group(1));
}
```

but i cannot write the regexPattern..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=")(.+)(?=")
```

In Java:

```
String regexPattern="(?<=\")(.+)(?=\")";
```

It uses look-behinds and lookaheads.

Group 1 will contain what you want.

Comment: You still need to escape the quotes: `"(?<=\")(.+)(?=\")"`.

Comment: if i don't want to match `//@Table(name = "T_MEM_MEMBER_ADDRESS")` and `//   @Table(name = "T_MEM_MEMBER_ADDRESS")`  ,how to write?

Comment: @AmitJoki I mean, if my strings also has `//@Table(name = "T_MEM_MEMBER_ADDRESS")` with // comments, I don't want my regexPattern matches this string

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code:

```
    String input = "@Table(name = \"T_MEM_MEMBER_ADDRESS1\")";
    String regexPattern=".*\"(.*)\".*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    boolean matches = matcher.matches();
    if (matches){
       System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Hope it helps.